# SQL in Linq: Group & Max for every column

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have to transform this SQL statement into Linq:

```
select id, workerId, max(timestamp) as Datex, clientId from order where clientId = '123' group by workerId;
```

It creates a table with every column of the table order. But it only displays the rows with clientID=123 and groups it by workers. It only shows the latest entry (max timestamp)

how can I transfer that into Linq? I tried everything. This for example doesn´t work:

```
var selectedOrder = from s in order
                    where s.clientID == "123"
                    group s by s.workerId into g
                    select new {  id = s.id, workerId = g.Key, Datex = g.Max(s => s.timestamp), s.clientID};
```

UPDATE:

1. I wanna give you an example:

> ```
> id: 1   workerId: 162   Datex: 2014-11-13   clientId: 123 
> id: 2   workerId: 162   Datex: 2016-01-07   clientId: 123 
> id: 3   workerId: 222   Datex: 2015-12-12   clientId: 123 
> id: 4   workerId: 222   Datex: 2013-01-22   clientId: 100 
> id: 2   workerId: 162   Datex: 2011-11-07   clientId: 123
> ```

due to the query I want:

> ```
>   id: 2   workerId: 162   Datex: 2016-01-07   clientId: 123 
>   id: 3   workerId: 222   Datex: 2015-12-12   clientId: 123
> ```

--> So there are only two different workers in my first table. I want to show the row with the latest Date for every worker

Comment: `id` column is not used in group by statement. are you sure you can run this sql query?

Comment: Yes it works. The idea is to show the latest Tupel of every workerId. So every workerId should appear only once.

Comment: In other words: I want to show the show the newest Tupel of every worker

Comment: really? And what value `id` has in output?

Comment: The value of the newest Tupel

Comment: I´m gonna update it and give you an example. It´s kind of hard to explain. But thanks for your time ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OrderBy` and use `First()`, query should look like

```
var selectedOrder = (from s in order
            where s.clientID == "123"
            select new
            {
                id = s.id,
                workerId = s.workerId,
                Datex = s.timestamp,
                clientID =s.clientID
            }).OrderBy(d => d.Datex).First();
```

or `GroupBy` Multiple Columns

```
var selectedOrder = from s in order
            where s.clientID == "123"
            group s by new {s.workerId, s.id, s.clientID}
            into g
            select
            new
            {
                id = g.Key.id,
                workerId = g.Key.workerId,
                Datex = g.Max(s => s.timestamp),
                clientID = g.Key.clientID
            };
```

Comment: The first Code only shows the very first Tupel of all workers. But I want to show the first Tupel of every worker